# Is it kosher to modify this.state in render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set a state to its default value if the component receives from elsewhere a null. Since there's no `componentWillReceiveState()`, I can only check for change in `componentWillUpdate()`. But from within that function I can't call `setState()`. At any rate since `componentWillUpdate()` isn't invoke during the initial render it'd be unreliable. The only way to do this it seems is to modify `this.state` directly in `render()`. I wonder whether that run afoul of certain rule or assumption.

Comment: If you had to update state in `render` you did something wrong. You said "if the component receives from a null" but it’s not clear where is this `null` come from?

Comment: The null is basically used to indicate the default value. Component knows better what that ought to be. It's hardly an usual design.

Comment: I still not understand what is the `null` we talking about? If we talking about `null` in the `state`, that means that your component sets the `state` attribute to `null` somewhere, right? like so: `this.setState({ attr: null })`. In this case you should replace `null` with the default value as David said. OR, as Clarkie said, just use default value in the `render` method when you found that value is null. OR update your question with the code sample

Comment: Sorry, a word somehow got left out of the question. The call to setState() is made from outside the component. Basically, setState() is used to deliver data to the component that it has requested earlier.

Comment: The disadvantage of using a condition in render() is that you won't see the default value in the React Dev toolbar. The other live-cycle functions will also not see the value. Setting this.state is just cleaner.

Comment: The root of you problem is here "The call to setState() is made from outside the component". You should use `props` to deliver data to the component. And never ever access state from outside. Maybe you will need to keep state higher up in the parent component.

Comment: I know that, We're talking about the parent component. It's where React stuff interfaces with non-React stuff. I want to normalize the data at this level before propagating it so my presentation components won't have to deal with missing props.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about state you should be able to just default to `null` when you call `setState` (when inside the lifecycle) or when using `constructor`/`getInitialState`.

Changing `this.state` is bad.

Comment: The reason it's a mistake in general to change this.state directly is that first, doing so does not trigger a rerender so the state object would be inconsistent with the presentation; second, there might be setState() in queue from earlier that would eventually overwrite your change. Neither of these is a concern in render(). That function is probably the only place where you can safely change this.state.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @oluckyman. If you are manipulating state in `render` something has gone wrong with your component structure.

You should be able to conditionally output certain bits of the component based on other variables (e.g. `this.props`)

```
render: function () {
    if (!this.props.foo) return null;

    // if you have some foo then do something else
}
```